# How do you mock out a static method of a domain object in Grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

have a Grails domain object that has a custom static function to grab data from the database

```
class Foo {
    /* member variables, mapping, constraints, etc. */

    static findByCustomCriteria(someParameter, List listParameter) {
        /* code to get stuff from the database... */

        /*
            Return value is a map
            ["one": "uno", "two": "due", "three": "tre"]
        */
    }

}
```

The static function `findByCustomCriteria` uses `createCriteria()` to build the query that pulls data from the Foo table, which means `mockDomain(Foo)` does not work properly when unit testing.  What I'm trying to do to work around this is use one of the general purpose methods of mocking to mock out `findByCustomCriteria`, but I can't get the syntax quite right.

I have a controller `BarController` that I'm trying to test, and buried in the call to `BarController.someFunction()` there is a call to `Foo.findByCustomCriteria()`.

```
class BarControllerTest extends ControllerUnitTestCase {

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testSomeFunction() {

        /* Mocking for Foo goes here */

        assertEquals("someValue", controller.someFunction())
    }
}
```

What would be a way to mock this out?

I've tried using `new MockFor()`, `mockFor()`, and `metaClass`, but I can't get it to work.

---

Edit:

Every time I tried to mock this out, I tried to mock it like so...

```
Foo.metaClass.'static'.findByCustomCriteria = { someParam, anotherParam ->
    ["one": "uno", "two": "due", "three": "tre"]
}
```

I guess I didn't include enough information initially.

Comment: put the mocking and foo stuff in...thats what we need to see to help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've encountered this scenario more than once, you need to modify the *static* metaClass of Foo:

```
Foo.metaClass.'static'.findByCustomCriteria = { someParameter, List listParameter ->
    ["one": "uno", "two": "due", "three": "tre"]
}
```

Typically I'll put it in the test setup, so I don't forget when it needs to be applied.

Comment: This solution does not work.  I'm updating the question accordingly.

Comment: @haydenmuhl: I updated the solution to include an explicit argument (I had assumed the implicit it parameter would be sufficient, but maybe not, which could be the issue (i.e. method overload signature)). Please try again.

Comment: Your solution probably would have worked, but I didn't include the right info in my question.  The method signature I was using was wrong.  It actually took an object and a list, and I was mocking it out as taking two objects.  I'll update the question.  If you update your answer, I'll select it as correct.

Comment: And make sure the method signatures match ;-)

Comment: I don't think the quotes around static are necessary.

Comment: @RyanHeathcote once upon a time, but I think you're right: not these days.

Answer (score 5):

In Grails 2.0 and higher, you can use the `GrailsMock` class like this

```
def mockControl = new GrailsMock(MyDomainClass)
mockControl.demand.static.get() {id -> return null}  // Static method
...
mockControl.verify()
```

See [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/api/grails/test/GrailsMock.html).